# php PUSH-server can't send multiply push-messages

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification

I have a php-script that fetches a couple of uuid's from a mysql database and then sends a message to all the users.
But it doesn't work when there are a lot of users.

The script can be found here: http://pastebin.com/VATM1eaC

On line 19, I have a commented $sql query. When I use that one it works. The two UUID's there are my and my friends. But when it fetches all UUID's from the database, it doesn't work (a know a couple of people in the database that doesn't get the PUSH.).
The database contains around 300 UUID's.

I tested added sleep(1) after each fwrite, to see if that helped, but it didn't. (It helped on another script, when I only pushed the message to me and my friend, but several times).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We use this library http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/ for sending push notifications to our users. We currently have around 40.000+ users and we send out over 200.000 push notifications a day without any problems.

I would check that library. It's easy to implement and works perfectly!